# Render a basic Quad to Screen?

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx

I have been trying to accomplish this for quite some time with no success; I've looked at several relevant questions here on StackOverflow with no success; I've also followed 6 different tutorials that ALL followed pretty much the same process:

1. Build the vertices: `-1, -1, 0`, `-1, 1, 0`, `1, 1, 0`, and `1, -1, 0`.
2. Build the indices: `0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3`.
3. Create the `Vertex` and `Index` buffers.
4. Clear the `RenderTargetView`.
5. Set the current `Vertex` and `Pixel` shaders.
6. Update the constant buffers if you have any.
7. Render the quad (see below).
8. Rinse and repeat `4 - 8`.

Now, the reason this is driving me up the wall is because I can render far more advanced objects such as:

- Spheres
- 3D Lines
- Fans

---

My code for creating the quad is pretty much the same as everyone else's:

```
public class Quad {
    private void SetVertices() {
        float width = Rescale(Size.Width, 0, Application.Width, -1, 1);
        float height = Rescale(Size.Height, 0, Application.Height, -1, 1);
        vertices = new Vertex[] {
            new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, -height, 0), Vector3.ForwardLH, Color.White),
            new Vertex(new Vector3(-width, height, 0), Vector3.ForwardLH, Color.White),
            new Vertex(new Vector3(width, height, 0), Vector3.ForwardLH, Color.White),
            new Vertex(new Vector3(width, -height, 0), Vector3.ForwardLH, Color.White)
        }
        indices = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
        vertexBuffer = Buffer.Create(Device3D, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, vertices);
        vertexBinding = new VertexBufferBinding(vertexBuffer, Utilities.SIzeOf<Vertex>(), 0);
        indexBuffer = Buffer.Create(Device3D, BindFlags.IndexBuffer, indices);
        indexCount = indices.Length;
    }
    public void Render() {
        if (shaderResourceView != null)
            context3D.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, shaderResourceView);
        context3D.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, samplerState);
        context3D.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip;
        context3D.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, vertexBinding);
        context3D.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(indexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0);
        context3D.DrawIndexed(totalIndexCount, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

---

### Notes

I am using a right handed coordinate system (for some reason the previous developer hardwired `Vector3.ForwardLH` into some places that I now cannot get rid of yet); if that helps any and I cannot currently convert to a left handed coordinate system.

---

Am I missing something here? Why am I unable to render a basic quad?

---

If you feel more information is needed feel free to let me know and I will add it on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering with Direct3D 11, you need to know the all the state. You do not mention what your BlendState, DepthStencilState, or RasterState settings are here which is a likely reason you aren't getting the results you want.

- If the DepthStencilState is such set use the Z-Buffer, then the fact that your vertices have a 0 for the Z means they are going to get culled. You can set a depth/stencil state without Z writes or Z tests, and you should definitely turn off Z writes when drawing 2D stuff anyhow. You can also pass something like `0.5` for the Z value for your vertices which is fairly common for 2D drawing with 3D APIs.
- If you backface culling enabled in the RasterState, then the winding order of your vertices could result in them being skipped. You can play with different winding orders, or disable culling.

It also really matters what your Vertex Shader and Pixel Shader are here. You don't show the code for setting your shaders or shader constants, and you don't show the HLSL.

You should seriously consider using the [SharpDX Toolkit](https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit) `SpriteBatch` class for efficient quad rendering or looking at their [source for it](https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit/blob/master/Source/Toolkit/SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs).

> I know you are using SharpDX an C#, *but* you might find it useful to see the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Simple-rendering) tutorial on drawing 2D shapes.